# Why does span padding cause the rendering box to overlap its parent?

Tags: html, css

See this jsfiddle for example:
  http://jsfiddle.net/FrJRA/1/
and note that the inner span's border overlaps the containing div.

I sort of understand what is happening. But I don't understand why. Why isn't the size of the `div` increased to allow for the new height of the `span`?

I know I can use `display: inline-block` if I want this to happen, but what is the reasoning behind `inline` failing to increase parent container size?

Comment: your URL is slightly wrong. It should be. http://jsfiddle.net/FrJRA/1

Comment: "Why isn't the size of the `div` increased" Why should it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inline elements only change their dimensions for padding in the left/right dimensions. It doesn't increase the dimension of the element in the top/bottom directions.  That's why you notice it increasing it on the sides but not on the top/bottom.

Update:
Found the part of the W3 specification that touches on this.

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box
>   start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do
>   with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when
>   calculating the height of the line box. [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)

Answer (score 3):

Inline elements just aren't meant to affect layout, that's why `block` or `inline-block` will but the `inline` span won't.

Comment: But they *do* affect layout; they affect the width of the parent just fine. And their margins add, right. Just not their padding...?

Comment: Hexxagonal's explanation is better; I'm not sure why inline dimensions can be partially changed, I just know that the theory is that they aren't meant to impact block-level elements. But you're right: reality insists that the two interact in some way.

Comment: They don't affect the width of their parents, except in special cases (floats and absolutely-positioned elements with no `width`, and table cell content).

Comment: Their content affects the parent. Or does the content really 'belong' to the parent, and the span is just decorating it?

Comment: For inline, the height is based entirely off of the calculated line-height.  I wouldn't think of it as belonging to the parent, but as the parent is composed of it's children.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` isn't meant to change size in this case. As `<span>` is an inline element.

If that is the functionality you are looking for amend

```
div, span {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

with `overflow:auto;`

```
 div, span {
     border: 1px solid gray;
     overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is going in the wrong direction--not only is the div not any bigger, but now it's got scrollbars too.